# Images from i.stack.imgur.com not loading

Tags: bug, imgur

Note: I did a goofup by ping/tracerouting to stack.imgur.com instead of i.stack.imgur.com, but the core problem remains the same, none of the images are visible to me.

Can anyone check on what's happening? I'm not too certain if it's localized just to me.

Traceroute completely fails.

```
C:\Users\Sathya>tracert i.stack.imgur.com

Tracing route to gsb1.wpc.v2cdn.net [68.232.45.253]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8
```

---

http://i.imm.io/N1KH.png

---

http://i.imm.io/N1In.png

Comment: Same story here

Comment: @Bart I did a goofup, have updated it - can you please check if you're facing the same?

Comment: Completes fine here

Comment: @MarcGravell yeah, it seems to be up now - was down for a good hour or so - gonna close it.

Comment: @Sathya Things seems to be fine now indeed. But I have had intermittent issues here as well. Does the stack.imgur use the same infrastructure as imgur itself? I have had a Cloudflare error page appear there several times, a service they seem to use...

Comment: @Bart yes, I believe the the same infrastructure is used - and I've been told by others that they've had intermittent issues too

Comment: Wish this question wasn't closed. Ive been having the same issue for about 6 months now. I just thought it was my office network blocking the connection to i.stack.imgur.com. I can't see any posted images from that domain, but I can see the site's logo and background images. Makes it hard to participate in GD.SE for sure.