# Are Images from i.stack.imgur.com permanent? AKA "Why are my pictures gone?"

Tags: support, images, uploader, broken-link

I got pinged with [this comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26396/unstretched-generated-texture-coordinates-for-normal-mapping#comment130674_26437):

> There aren't any images.

Upon closer inspection, I realized that not only are my answer's images gone, but the other answer also.
This got me looking and I found these posts (none of which were helpful) and this question is *not* a duplicate of any of them:

- [Images from i.stack.imgur.com not loading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156757/278094)
- [i.stack.imgur.com images stop working after a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111619/278094)
- [Images manually uploaded to Imgur are not displaying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95732/278094)
  or
- [Is i.stack.imgur.com deleting images?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108946/278094)

In that last question there is a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108946/is-i-stack-imgur-com-deleting-images#comment281174_108946):

> It does work for these images, if you're referring to those embedded in the example question you linked. If it doesn't, then the image was deleted because it was inactive for 6 months.

That makes it sound as if nobody looked at a particular question for six months, all the images would get deleted!

Are images uploaded through SE's image hosting tool subject to such deletion rules? (I sure hope not!)

If this is not the case why are the images from [that question's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/26396/2217) answers now gone?

Comment: Images are permanent, but Imgur's been having issues the last couple of days. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291609/intermittent-failed-to-upload-image-imgur-is-rejecting-the-request

Comment: I see this is much more wide spread then I thought. Now trying to upload a image of the user page with many missing avatars, the image upload fails.

Comment: @David There's an S3 outage right now, and imgur is affected by it

Comment: You mean the temporary and unplanned increase in error rate to 100%?